# Как правильно оформить внутреннюю гиперссылку к документу HTML?

Tags: html, разметка

Здравствуйте, дорогие программисты! Собственно я уже поздоровалась, поэтому сразу к делу: как создавать внутренние гиперссылки в HTML, в блокноте желательно, я плохо понимаю, что это такое.

Comment: Со мной никто не здоровался ='(

Comment: Очень жаль.))Сдравствуй!))

Comment: ПрИвЕт! =)

Comment: Ответить надо!))

Answer (score 3):

Еще наверное стоит сказать что якорь вставляется в место в тексте, куда нужно переходить и выглядит так:

```
<a name="имя_якоря"></a>
```

переход на него осуществляется так (если переход внутри страницы):

```
<a href="#имя_якоря">Ссылка на якорь внутри документа</a>
```

или (если переход на якорь внутри другой страницы):

```
<a href="имя_страницы.htm#имя_якоря>Ссылка на якорь в другом документе</a>
```

Comment: ну вообще-то якорем может быть любой тег HTML, не обязательно 
<pre><code><a name="имя_якоря"></a></code></pre>
может быть и так написано
<pre><code><span name="имя_якоря"></span><br />
<div name="имя_якоря"></div></code></pre>

Comment: Возможно, но я такие наверное редко встречал, или просто не обращал внимания. В первом попавшемся инернет-учебнике html описывается именно `<a name="...">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="page.html">Страница</a>
```

- page.html - целевая страница
- Страница - текст ссылки

либо

```
<a href="#target">Абзац</a>
```

- #target - целевой якорь
- Абзац - текст ссылки

Answer (score 0):

Ссылки в хтмл пишутся так

```
<a href='#'>Ссылка</a>
```

Вместо # адрес страницы